# How to execute threads in an interleaved way in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I am almost new in Python threading.
This is my code modeled on an example code found on GeeksForFeeks which explains threads behavior using lock.
But the result - for me - is counterintuitive.

```
import threading 

# global variable x 
x = 0

# creating a lock 
lock = threading.Lock() 

def increment(): 
    global x 
    x += 1
    print("thread1:", x)
    
def decrement(): 
    global x 
    x -= 1
    print("thread2:", x)
  
def plus(): 
    global lock
    for _ in range(100000): 
        lock.acquire() 
        increment()
        lock.release()

def minus(): 
    global lock
    for _ in range(100000): 
        lock.acquire() 
        decrement()
        lock.release()
  
def main_task(): 
    global x 
    # setting global variable x as 0 
    x = 0

    # creating threads 
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=plus) 
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=minus)
  
    # start threads 
    t1.start() 
    t2.start() 
  
    # wait until threads finish their job 
    t1.join() 
    t2.join() 
  
if __name__ == "__main__": 
        main_task()
```

I would expect a result like this:

```
thread1: 1
thread2: 0
thread1: 1
thread2: 0
thread1: 1
thread2: 0
thread1: 1
...
```

but instead I obtain

```
thread1: 1
thread1: 2
thread1: 3
thread1: 4
thread1: 5
thread1: 6
thread1: 7
...
thread1: 151
thread2: 150
thread2: 149
thread2: 148
thread2: 147
thread2: 146
thread2: 145
thread2: 144
thread2: 143
thread2: 142
thread2: 141
...
```

Why does thread2 cannot acquire lock each time it is released from thread1?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens for at least two reasons:

1. The `GIL` is a single lock on the interpreter itself which adds a rule that execution of any Python bytecode requires acquiring the interpreter lock.
2. More general: The `Lock` object is not quite right for you. Yes, it synchronizes access to the variable, but after the `lock` is released and before the moment it is acquired, other code can perform several such iterations.

For interleaved synchronization, it is better to use the [`Condition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition) object, which allows the code to wait for other code to notify (essentially wake it up) that the first can execute:

```
# creating a lock
lock = threading.Condition()

# ...

def plus():
    global lock
    with lock:
        for _ in range(100000):
            increment()
            lock.notify()
            lock.wait()
        lock.notify()  # notify to finish companion thread


def minus():
    global lock
    with lock:
        for _ in range(100000):
            decrement()
            lock.notify()
            lock.wait()
        lock.notify()  # notify to finish companion thread
```

```
...
thread1: 1
thread2: 0
thread1: 1
thread2: 0
thread1: 1
thread2: 0
```

Comment: Thank you. Why `Condition` object does not allow other things to run once once the resource is released while the `Lock` object does allow please?

Comment: Because in the case of Condition, we wait (wait() method) for another thread to work and notify (notify() method) us of it. This achieves synchronization. In the case of a Lock, immediately after releasing it we try to acquire it again.

Comment: In case we have multiple threads spawned from a thread processing a queue data, do you still we need `Condition` object, please?